# Create columns in MySQL from row values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    datetime
    , close
    , CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 30 THEN close END as t1
    , CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 35 THEN close END as t2
    , CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 40 THEN close END as t3
    , CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 45 THEN close END as t4
FROM some_table;
```

Which produces the following output:
[image]

What I need is a single row per day with values for t1, t2, t3, t4. I am basically trying to extract values from a particular date, hour and minute and store them as separate columns for ML processing later.

Somehow I need to flatten the table but not sure how I would achieve that.

Thank you.

Comment: Add proper GROUP BY, wrap columns expressions (CASE WHEN) with MAX(), remove `close` column from the output list, add according WHERE for to decrease the amount of scanned rows.

Answer (score 0):

Answer below thanks to comment above from @Akina.

```
SELECT
    date
    , MAX(close) as t_all
    , MAX(CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 30 THEN close END) as t1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 35 THEN close END) as t2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 40 THEN close END) as t3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN hour = 13 and minute = 45 THEN close END) as t4
FROM some_table
GROUP BY 1
```